# How do i find the current version of yesod on fpcomplete site

Tags: haskell, yesod, http-conduit

I would like some more information than just that, but the yesod version number (including minor version) would be a start.
I am noticing that my datamodel file is taking too long to compile (minutes) quite often. In order to understand the bottleneck, I wanted to get a local image of yesod running on fpcomplete. It so happens that the current version of [`Network.HTTP.Conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html) does not export [`def`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default/docs/Data-Default.html#v:def).

1. What are the minimum dependencies that I need to install and their versions to get an image identical to the one running of fpcomplete. Is there a file that I can use to build my project locally? The project.cabal generation feature might be useful here.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer for what's in an FP Complete environment is "The haskell platform for the selected environment plus stackage". Exactly which build of stackage is a bit harder to figure out, but it's recent.

Then there's this:
http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130922-179/

Comment: I see that the yesod version is yesod-1.2.2.1. I am going to try to install and see if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up using the latest version from the site and develop locally. Once fpcomplete upgrades, I will update the project.